# Does randomly changing the image every refresh hurt the SEO of the page?

Tags: seo, images, change-frequency

The web page has an `img` tag which displays an image of an eagle. However, it displays a different eagle (from a set of five eagles) 
every time. Does it affect the SEO of the page?

Joomla has a RandomImage module similar to the functionality explained above and Drupal as well has something similar.   If I use one of them or my own implementation will it hurt the rankings of the page?

Comment: If the alt tag is a good description for all five eagles then they are perfectly fine. A good description is one that is accurate.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Do you mean the alt tag for the five images(though all are eagles) should be distinct/unique among them? Also is Google is ok with seeing five different versions of the same page every time?

Comment: Eagle is pretty broad and would not be considered good for both user experience and SEO. Using just eagle means you will lose a lot of the more specific keyword searches particularly in Google image search. For example, if we're talking about a bald eagle with a white head, then we would be talking 'an adult Bald Eagle', if the eagle was flying, then it would be better to use the alt flying adult bald eagle but if it the eagle was flying over some mountains for example, then it would be best to include that information too, for example: 'adult flying bald eagle over ice cold mountains'.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, the SEO would be affected as the bot crawls the page and sees a specific alt tag as it goes through. The next time it goes by it might see a different alt tag. However if the images are similar, then the alt tags would be similar as well.

If all of the other content of the page stays the same, then the alt tag(s) would represent a very small fraction of code being read and would have an extremely limited impact on SEO.